# How is it possible to add new column to existing Dataframe in Spark SQL

Tags: dataframe, java-8, apache-spark-sql

I use [DataFrame API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html).

I have existing DataFrame and a List object (can also use Array). How is it possible to add this List to existing DataFrame as a new column? Should I use the class [Column](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html) for this?

Answer (score 5):

You should probably convert your List to a single Column RDD and apply join on critetia pickeg by you. Simple DataFrame conversion:

```
 val df1 = sparkContext.makeRDD(yourList).toDF("newColumn")
```

If you need to create additional column to perform join on you can add more columns, mapping your list:

```
val df1 = sparkContext.makeRDD(yourList).map(i => (i, fun(i)).toDF("newColumn", "joinOnThisColumn")
```

I am not familiar with Java version, but you should try using `JavaSparkContext.parallelize(yourList)` and apply similar mapping operations based on [this doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDD.html).

Comment: ok, thanks, I will try your solution. However I have found also some function in API Java, not Scala. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, It was my fault, I already found the function `withColumn(String colName, Column col)` which should solve my problem

Comment: The only problem with withColumn is it will be difficult to pick up elements from your list sequentially and add them to selected rows. If you have a way to do this, it is probably better this way but your question is to generic to tell ;)

Comment: Why, I will convert my List first of all to Column object and add it like second function argument. Is it not ok?...

Comment: Interesting. Please post how you did it after you finish.

Comment: @Niemand, the main problem is a cast (conversion) from ArrayList to Column object, is not going.. Did you mean this before?

Comment: Yep, this is more or less what i was thinking about. I thought you found a way to overcome this.

Comment: No, sorry. I'm newcomer in Spark... Sorry, can you please get your solution in Java, not in Scala. I don't know this language.

Comment: Edited my answer, I hope I could help more, but I am not familiar with Java-spark.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example where we had a column date and wanted to add another column with month.

```
Dataset<Row> newData = data.withColumn("month", month((unix_timestamp(col("date"), "MM/dd/yyyy")).cast("timestamp")));
```

Hoping this helps !

Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

This thread is a little old, but I ran into a similar situation using Java. I think more than anything, there was a conceptual misunderstanding of how I should approach this problem.

To fix my issue, I created a simple POJO to assist with the new column for a Dataset (as opposed to trying to build on an existing one). I think conceptually, I didn't understand that it was best to generate the Dataset during the initial read where the additional column needed to be added. I hope this helps someone in the future.

Consider the following:

```
        JavaRDD<MyPojo> myRdd = dao.getSession().read().jdbc("jdbcurl","mytable",someObject.getProperties()).javaRDD().map( new Function<Row,MyPojo>() {

                       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                       @Override
                       public MyPojo call(Row row) throws Exception {
                       Integer curDos = calculateStuff(row);   //manipulate my data

                       MyPojo pojoInst = new MyPojo();

                       pojoInst.setBaseValue(row.getAs("BASE_VALUE_COLUMN"));
                       pojoInst.setKey(row.getAs("KEY_COLUMN"));
                       pojoInst.setCalculatedValue(curDos);

                       return pojoInst;
                      }
                    });

         Dataset<Row> myRddRFF = dao.getSession().createDataFrame(myRdd, MyPojo.class);

//continue load or other operation here...
```